# How to set Doctrine unique row that depends on two columns and their values?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have table that contains also removed and current values, depends on column named ghost. Ghost 1 means that the row is removed and 0 means is persistent.

```
id | name | ghost
1  | nam1 | 1
2  | nam1 | 1
3  | nam1 | 0
```

How can I describe it with doctrine to ommit those rows with ghost = 1 for unique check and check unique only those with ghost = 0? Name should be unique only when ghost value is 0, otherwise row marked as ghost = 1 should be ommited, because is removed.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not provide any information about what kind of database system is used. That might be of some help.

But regardless of the underlying database, the simplest way is probably to set a combined unique constraint on both fields `name` and `ghost`.

As doctrine annotation:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="tablename",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="unique_name_ghost", columns={"name", "ghost"})})
 */
class YourEntity
{
}
```

or in sql:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_name_ghost UNIQUE (name, ghost);
```

However, this has an **additional implication**, namely that the combination of `ghost = 1` and `name` can also exist only once in that table. Your question doesn't state clearly wether it is a requirement to have multiple soft-deleted rows with the same name or not.

And by the way, there is a doctrine extension for soft-delete: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/softdeleteable.md. You might want to consider using that extension instead of doing the soft-delete manually.